# How to refund gas to the smart contract caller? (What is the number?)

Tags: contract-development, gas-estimate, gas-refund

I have this function:

```
    function setAccount(BaseUBI _ubi, address _user, uint256 _startTime, uint _esiaID, bool _setToZero) external {
        uint256 _refund = (gasleft() + 0/*FIXME*/) * tx.gasprice;
        require(msg.sender == server, "System function"); // don't refund otherwise
        require(_refund <= balances[_user], "Not enough balance");
        balances[_user] -= _refund; // must be called before transfer() against reentrancy attack
        server.transfer(_refund); // refund gas to the server
        _ubi.setAccount{gas: balances[_user]}(_user, _startTime, _esiaID, _setToZero);
        // We may be in a wrong state now, don't change any variables here.
    }
```

Which number should be in place of TODO to ensure that the server will receive back at least as much gas as it spent?

Is there a library that automates this task?

If necessary, rewrite the appropriate part of the above code in assembler.

Comment: Question edited: there was a security bug in the code in the question.

Comment: `balances[_user] -= _refund;` should come before `server.transfer(_refund);`.

Comment: @goodvibration Why? In Ethereum the entire transaction succeeds or the entire transaction fails. So the order is not important. Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: You must reduce the user's balance before sending the transaction. Otherwise, your contract is susceptible to a reentrancy attack: https://medium.com/coinmonks/protect-your-solidity-smart-contracts-from-reentrancy-attacks-9972c3af7c21

Comment: Have a look at the Checks, Effects and Interactions pattern to avoid the possibilities of reentrancy attacks https://fravoll.github.io/solidity-patterns/checks_effects_interactions.html

Comment: I've edited the code in the question, it had a bug

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use a modifier to do this.

```
modifier refundGas {
uint256 gasAtStart = gasleft();
_;
uint256 gasSpent = gasAtStart - gasleft() + 28925;
msg.sender.transfer(gasSpent * tx.gasprice);
}

function anyFunction() refundGas public {
    // Do something
}
```

**Note:** The number `28925` is an approx. of the `gas used for calculations` + `transfer` at the end. I've run on remix and put that here. However, it might be slightly off as well

However, I also think if you would refund gas then someone possibly could waste all the ETH inside the contract in refunds. For e.g., `server` could intentionally set a very high gas price even if it's unnecessary to do so, knowing that the contract would refund them 100%.

Comment: The question was about a number that _warrants_ that all the gas (or more) will be refunded.

Comment: Oh, I see, my code was wrong. Should refund only if the request was sent from `server`.

Comment: Also, yes the refunds should probably be limited to known/authorized users only. That might reduce misuses.